# Python - Iter through identified component features

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

I am standing in front of a huge problem. Using the python libraries NumPy and SciPy, I identified several features in large array. For this purpose, I created a 3x3 neighbor structure and used it for a connected component analysis --> see [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html#scipy.ndimage.measurements.label).

```
struct = scipy.ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2,2)
labeled_array, num_features = ndimage.label(array,struct)
```

My problem now is that I want to iterate through all identified features in a loop. Someone has an idea how to address individual features in the resulting NumPy array?

Comment: If you haven't already, be sure to take a look at scikits-image (http://scikits-image.org/).  It provides many more image processing algorithms than scipy.ndimage.

Comment: looks like a very promising library. I'll go for it, if speed and re-usability of my snippet goes further down. Unless you spontaneously know some nice feature addressing functions in scikits-image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of handling features identified by ndimage.label.  Whether this helps you or not depends on what you want to do with the features.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Make a small array for the demonstration.
# The ndimage.label() function treats 0 as the "background".
a = np.zeros((16, 16), dtype=int)
a[:6, :8] = 1
a[9:, :5] = 1
a[8:, 13:] = 2
a[5:13, 6:12] = 3

struct = ndi.generate_binary_structure(2, 2)
lbl, n = ndi.label(a, struct)

# Plot the original array.
plt.figure(figsize=(11, 4))
plt.subplot(1, n + 1, 1)
plt.imshow(a, interpolation='nearest')
plt.title("Original")
plt.axis('off')

# Plot the isolated features found by label().
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    # Make an array of zeros the same shape as `a`.
    feature = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=int)

    # Set the elements that are part of feature i to 1.
    # Feature i consists of elements in `lbl` where the value is i.
    # This statement uses numpy's "fancy indexing" to set the corresponding
    # elements of `feature` to 1.
    feature[lbl == i] = 1

    # Make an image plot of the feature.
    plt.subplot(1, n + 1, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(feature, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.copper)
    plt.title("Feature {:d}".format(i))
    plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Here's the image generated by the script:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this straight-forward solution. I didn't know about NumPy fancy indexing. After i have identified the individual features, i want to get the number of zero cells in direct vicinity to the feature. I already extracted the feature size by calling "sum(array[array>0])"

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note on an alternative way to solve the above mentioned problem. Instead of using the NumPy "fanzy indexing" one could also use the ndimage "find_objects" function.
example:

```
# Returns a list of slices for the labeled array. The slices represent the position of features in the labeled area 
s = ndi.find_objects(lbl, max_label=0)
# Then you can simply output the patches  
for i in n:
    print a[s[i]]
```

I will leave the question open because i couldn't solve an additional arising problem. I want to get the size of the features (already solved, quite easy via ndi.sum() ) as well as the number of nonlabeled cells in direct vicinity of the feature (ergo counting the number of zeros around the feature).